# WPF Usercontrol is not disposed

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

In short: Calling dispose manually and set reference as null doesn't dispose user control instance from hosting window.

I have a window which dynamically adds/remove instances of user control into grid panel (Window). All instances are disposed of when the window is closed. However, in my case, I need to keep window active but need to add/remove the instance of user control dynamically.

I have attached ANTS memory profile screenshot which shows the hierarchy in which it is staying alive. For me it looks like, an interop call is still pending/referring to `HwndKeyboardInputProvider`. If I assume to be correct, I am not sure how to get the handle of this unmanaged reference to dispose in my dispose method.

Can someone help me to implement clean disposal for my user control instance?

**User control XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CTWPFControls.CTWPFTextbox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Name="ctTextBox"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid x:Name="root">
        <TextBox d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=ctTextBox, Path=BindText}" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" 
                 TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" PreviewTextInput="textBox1_PreviewTextInput" 
                 GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ctTextBox, Path=EnableSpellCheck}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CTWPFControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CTWPFTextbox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CTWPFTextbox : UserControl,IDisposable
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {

        textBox1.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;
        textBox1.PreviewTextInput -= textBox1_PreviewTextInput;
        textBox1.GotFocus -= TextBox_GotFocus;
        textBox1.LostFocus -= TextBox_LostFocus;
        textBox1.KeyDown -= TextBox_OnKeyDown;
        textBox1 = null;
        ctTextBox = null;             

        }
        // Need this for binding in the credit search....or anywhere else for that matter
        public static DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BindText", typeof(string), typeof(CTWPFTextbox));

        public static DependencyProperty CanEnableSpellCheckProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "EnableSpellCheck", typeof(bool), typeof(CTWPFTextbox));
        public event TextChangedEventHandler TextChanged;

        public bool EnableSpellCheck
        {

            get { return (bool)GetValue(SpellCheck.IsEnabledProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SpellCheck.IsEnabledProperty, value); }
        }

        public string BindText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public enum EditType { AlphaNumeric, Numeric, Alphabetic, Telephone, NoSymbols, Decimal, Money, Date, IncomeExpText, LookupSearch }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return this.textBox1.Text; }
            set
            {

                string controlText;

                controlText = this.ValidateControlText(value);

                if (this.TextBoxType == EditType.AlphaNumeric || this.TextBoxType == EditType.Alphabetic || this.TextBoxType == EditType.NoSymbols)
                    if (this.AutoFormat)
                        controlText = ValidateAlphaTextBox(controlText);

                if (this.TextBoxType == EditType.Numeric || this.TextBoxType == EditType.IncomeExpText)
                    if (this.AutoFormat)
                        controlText = this.FormatNumeric(controlText);

                this.textBox1.Text = controlText;
            }
        }

        public int MaxLength
        {
            get { return this.textBox1.MaxLength; }
            set { textBox1.MaxLength = value; }
        }

        public bool ReadOnly
        {
            get { return this.textBox1.IsReadOnly; }
            set { this.textBox1.IsReadOnly = value; }
        }

        public TextWrapping TextWrap
        {
            get { return this.textBox1.TextWrapping; }
            set { this.textBox1.TextWrapping = value; }
        }


        [DefaultValue(EditType.AlphaNumeric)]
        public EditType TextBoxType { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool HasDecimals { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool AutoFormat { get; set; }

        public CTWPFTextbox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string FormatNumeric(string controlText)
        {
            decimal controlValue;
            string returnValue;

            if (controlText == string.Empty)
                return string.Empty;

            if (controlText.IndexOf(".") == 0)
            {
                if (controlText.Length == 1)
                    returnValue = "0";
                else
                    returnValue = string.Format("0{0}", controlText);
            }

            try { controlValue = decimal.Parse(controlText); }
            catch { return controlText; }

            if (!this.HasDecimals)
            {
                System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo format = (new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-gb")).NumberFormat;
                format.NumberDecimalDigits = 0;
                returnValue = controlValue.ToString("n", format);
            }
            else
                returnValue = controlValue.ToString("N");

            return returnValue;
        }

        private static bool IsValidOtherKey(Key key)
        {
            if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) != 0)
                return true;

            if ((key < Key.D0 && key != Key.Space) || (key > Key.Z && key < Key.NumPad0))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        private static bool IsValidDecimalKey(TextBox textBox, Key key)
        {
            if (IsValidIntegerKey(textBox, key))
                return true;
            if (key == Key.Decimal)
                return !textBox.Text.Contains(".");

            return false;
        }

        private static bool IsValidIntegerKey(TextBox textBox, Key key)
        {
            if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) != 0)
                return false;
            if (Key.D0 <= key && key <= Key.D9)
                return true;
            if (Key.NumPad0 <= key && key <= Key.NumPad9)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public static string ValidateAlphaTextBox(string controlText)
        {
            int currentPosition = 0;
            string currentWord = string.Empty;
            string returnText = string.Empty;
            char currentCharacter;

            if (controlText == null || controlText.Length == 0)
                return string.Empty;

            while (currentPosition < controlText.Length)
            {
                currentCharacter = controlText[currentPosition];

                if (currentCharacter == '\t' || currentCharacter == '\n' || currentCharacter == ' ')
                {
                    if (currentWord.Length != 0)
                    {
                        currentWord = string.Format("{0}{1}", currentWord.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper(),
                            currentWord.Length == 1 ? string.Empty : currentWord.Substring(1, currentWord.Length - 1).ToLower());
                    }

                    returnText += currentWord + currentCharacter;
                    currentWord = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                    currentWord += currentCharacter;

                currentPosition++;
            }

            if (currentWord.Length != 0)
            {
                currentWord = string.Format("{0}{1}", currentWord.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper(),
                    currentWord.Length == 1 ? string.Empty : currentWord.Substring(1, currentWord.Length - 1).ToLower());

                returnText += currentWord;
            }

            return returnText;
        }

        private string ValidateControlText(string controlText)
        {
            char[] characterArray;
            string textValue = string.Empty;

            if (controlText == null)
                return string.Empty;

            // Allow any text in the alpha numeric control
            if (this.TextBoxType == EditType.AlphaNumeric)
                return controlText.Replace("'", "`");

            // Remove anything after the decimal point for numberic type if decimals are not allowed
            if (this.HasDecimals == false && this.TextBoxType == EditType.Numeric)
            {
                int decimalIndex;

                if ((decimalIndex = controlText.IndexOf(".")) != -1)
                    controlText = controlText.Substring(0, decimalIndex);
            }

            // Retrieve the string as a character array
            characterArray = controlText.ToCharArray();

            // Step through each character validating it
            for (int index = 0; index < characterArray.Length; index++)
            {
                switch (this.TextBoxType)
                {
                    case EditType.Alphabetic:
                        if (this.ValidateAlphabeticInput(characterArray[index]))
                            textValue += characterArray[index];

                        break;

                    case EditType.Numeric:
                        if (this.ValidateNumericInput(characterArray[index]))
                            textValue += characterArray[index];

                        break;

                    case EditType.IncomeExpText:
                        if (this.ValidateNumericInput(characterArray[index]))
                            textValue += characterArray[index];

                        break;

                    case EditType.Telephone:
                        if (this.ValidateNumericInput(characterArray[index]))
                            textValue += characterArray[index];

                        break;

                    case EditType.NoSymbols:
                        if (this.ValidateNoSymbolInput(characterArray[index]))
                            textValue += characterArray[index];

                        break;

                    case EditType.Decimal:
                        if (this.ValidateDecimalInput(characterArray[index]))
                            textValue += characterArray[index];

                        break;
                }
            }

            // Set the control's text
            return textValue;
        }

        private bool ValidateAlphabeticInput(char keyChar)
        {
            char[] validCharacters = new char[] { ' ', '`', ',', '.', '-', '_', '@', '/' };

            // Check if the character is part of the lower case alphabet
            if (keyChar >= 'a' && keyChar <= 'z')
                return true;

            // Check if the character is part of the upper case alphabet
            if (keyChar >= 'A' && keyChar <= 'Z')
                return true;

            // Step through our list of valid characters
            foreach (char validCharacter in validCharacters)
            {
                // If the character is in the list of characters, it is valid
                if (validCharacter == (char)keyChar)
                    return true;
            }

            // The character inputted is not allowed in this mode
            return false;
        }

        private bool ValidateNumericInput(char keyChar)
        {
            // Check if the character is a numeric character
            if (keyChar >= '0' && keyChar <= '9')
                return true;

            if (this.TextBoxType == EditType.Numeric || this.TextBoxType == EditType.Decimal)
            {
                // If the character is a decimal place, ensure it is the only one
                if (keyChar == '.' && this.Text.IndexOf('.') == -1 && this.HasDecimals)
                    return true;
            }

            // Do not allow the character
            return false;
        }

        private bool ValidateDecimalInput(char keyChar)
        {
            // Check if the character is a numeric character
            if (keyChar >= '0' && keyChar <= '9')
                return true;

            // If the character is a decimal place, ensure it is the only one
                if (keyChar == '.')
                    return true;

            // Do not allow the character
            return false;
        }

        private bool ValidateNoSymbolInput(char keyChar)
        {
            // Check if the character is part of the lower case alphabet
            if (keyChar >= 'a' && keyChar <= 'z')
                return true;

            // Check if the character is part of the upper case alphabet
            if (keyChar >= 'A' && keyChar <= 'Z')
                return true;

            // Allow numerical digits
            if (keyChar >= '0' && keyChar <= '9')
                return true;

            // Allow the space character
            if (keyChar == ' ')
                return true;

            // The character inputted is not allowed in this mode
            return false;
        }

        public static bool IsValidAlphaKey(Key key)
        {
            if ((Key.A <= key && key <= Key.Z) || key == Key.Space)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.textBox1.Text.Length == 0 && (TextBoxType != EditType.Telephone && TextBoxType != EditType.Alphabetic && TextBoxType != EditType.AlphaNumeric && TextBoxType != EditType.IncomeExpText && TextBoxType != EditType.LookupSearch))
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = "0";
                return;
            }

            else if (TextBoxType == EditType.Money)
            {
                double temp = double.Parse(this.textBox1.Text);
                this.textBox1.Text = Math.Round(temp, 2).ToString();
            }

            else if (TextBoxType == EditType.Numeric || TextBoxType == EditType.IncomeExpText)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = this.FormatNumeric(this.textBox1.Text);
            }

            else if (TextBoxType == EditType.Alphabetic)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = ValidateAlphaTextBox(this.textBox1.Text);
            }
        }

        private void TextBox_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValidOtherKey(e.Key))
                return;

            if (TextBoxType == EditType.Numeric || TextBoxType == EditType.Telephone || TextBoxType == EditType.IncomeExpText)
                e.Handled = !IsValidIntegerKey(this.textBox1, e.Key);
            else if (TextBoxType == EditType.Decimal || TextBoxType == EditType.Money)
                e.Handled = !IsValidDecimalKey(this.textBox1, e.Key);
            else if (TextBoxType == EditType.Alphabetic)
                e.Handled = !IsValidAlphaKey(e.Key);
        }

        private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                base.OnGotFocus(e);
                this.textBox1.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if (this.TextBoxType == EditType.Numeric || this.TextBoxType == EditType.IncomeExpText)
                this.textBox1.Text = this.textBox1.Text.Replace(",", string.Empty);

            this.textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
            this.textBox1.SelectionLength = this.textBox1.Text.Length;

            base.OnGotFocus(e);
            this.textBox1.Focus();
        }

        private void textBox1_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextBoxType == EditType.Numeric || TextBoxType == EditType.Telephone || TextBoxType == EditType.IncomeExpText)
                e.Handled = IsValidNewIntegerKey(e.Text);
            else if (TextBoxType == EditType.Alphabetic)
                e.Handled = IsValidNewAlphaKey(e.Text);
            else if (TextBoxType == EditType.LookupSearch)
                e.Handled = IsValidLookupKey(e.Text);
        }

        public static bool IsValidNewAlphaKey(string key)
        {
            if (key == " ")
                return false;

            string allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-'";

            if (allowedChars.IndexOf(key) >= 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        public static bool IsValidLookupKey(string key)
        {
            string allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-'%0123456789";

            if (allowedChars.IndexOf(key) >= 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;                
        }

        private static bool IsValidNewIntegerKey(string key)
        {
            string allowedChars = "0123456789";

            if (allowedChars.IndexOf(key) >= 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextChangedEventHandler h = TextChanged;
            if (h != null)
                h(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**References:**

1. If it helps, a similar issue was reported in MSDN forum but the solution wasn't clear enough when it comes to `HwndKeyboardInputProvider`. I am tagging the link [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/64e7968f-1fa9-4bbf-9de3-20ed9510dc2f/memory-leak-in-effectivevalueentry-with-custom-combo-box?forum=wpf)

Comment: Obviously question.  Keyboard input deals with typing in text and you have a textbox there. When you try and dispose it, does your textbox maybe have focus?

Comment: @Andy, Thanks for your comment. To answer: It doesn't since addition/removal is triggered through the click of a button. Upon click, the focus will be moved to button.  NOTE: The above screenshot is a single GC root of one of the instances of the user controls. However, in reality, the user can remove one or more instance of user controls and there will be active GC roots equivalent number of user control instances. This cause the UI to drop performance linearly as the user proceeds through the day.